# Webdriver vs. browser

Tags: webdriver

On the server side, is there any way to distinguish a request coming from an automated script from selenium webdriver vs. a request made by a physical user?

Comment: Depends on how well the script simulates a real user.

Answer (score 0):

You could have webdriver set a specific cookie during its request, that way you know when you're dealing with a webdriver request.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the browser you're using or your implementation of the test, you could pass a header to the http request.
If you use chrome, you can build something to use ModifyHeaders extension. I'm sure you can use other similar things in firefox.
Another alternative is to use FiddlerCore in your testing framework and intercept  the request and pass the custom header.
There are multiple other alternatives as well. Can you specify a little bit more where do you want to know who's running the test?